How do I make a 3D crystal lattice using TikZ?
I've been trying to make a decent 3D crystal lattice using LaTeX and TikZ for a while now, and I finally managed to find some code where someone had made a perfect one. However, no matter what I try, instead of a 3D lattice, I get a mess of randomly oriented spherical parts.


Below is the code that I used(https://github.com/dog-blood/utterly-unorganized-latex-code/tree/main/Chem/Unit%203%20Gasses):
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=180,line cap=round,line join=round,scale=0.8]
    
    
    \tikzset{xy/.style={canvas is xy plane at       z=\a,shift={(0.5*\a,0.5*\a)},rotate=90*\i,fill=red1,draw=pag!30},
        xz/.style={canvas is xz plane at y=\a,shift={(0.5*\a,0.5*\a)},rotate=90*\i,fill=red1,draw=pag!30},
        yz/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=\a,shift={(0.5*\a,0.5*\a)},rotate=90*\i,fill=red1,draw=pag!30},
        my ball/.style={top color=red2, bottom color=red2}}
    
    
    \def\a{3} % edge length
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{0.25*sqrt(2.5)*\a} % sphere radius
    % background
    \foreach\i in {0,120,240}
    \draw[rotate=\i,color=pag!,my ball] (\a,0,0) --++ (0,\r,0) arc (90:135:\r) arc (0:60:\r cm)
    {[canvas is xz plane at y=0] arc (135:90:\r)} -- cycle;
    % sphere (center)
    \draw[my ball, color=pag]  (0.5*\a,0.5*\a,0.5*\a) circle (\r cm);
    % foreground
    \foreach\i in {0,120,240}
    \draw[rotate=\i,my ball,color=pag] (\a,\a,0) --++ (60:\r cm) arc (60:120:\r cm) -- cycle;
    
    \foreach\s in {xy,xz,yz} \foreach\i in {1,...,4}
    \draw[\s] (45:{\a*sin(45)}) --++ (180:\r) arc (180:270:\r) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


I found my mistake, it was an early morning and I forgot to add:
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

